# Adding static library to project >> Undefined symbols

Tags: ios, xcode

I have created a static library which I added to another project in the same workspace in XCode. The library builds fine, both for Simulator and an actual device.

All errors refer to classes in the library, so it's not about another framework.

I get two undefined symbols errors that both refer to "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Campaign"
When I build for an actual device I get **Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s**
When I build for a simulator I get **Undefined symbols for architecture i386**

I tried creating a fat library: same issue.
I toggled "build for active architecture only" on and off: doesn't help.
I deleted and rebuilt the XCode workspace: no solution.

I'm very sure I added the correct .m files to the "compile sources" of the library, and I properly added the library to the other project through "Link binary with libraries". I also tried just dragging the .lib to the Frameworks folder.

I added the header file of the .lib to the project.

I would be glad with any suggestion!

Comment: Can you post `Campaign.h`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely caused by the fact that your static library import something from another library.

You need to figure out what symbols are missing exactly and add library that defines them. Build log output should be very helpful in this regard.

**EDIT:** Based on discussion in comments, problem is caused by the fat that there's no implementation for `Campaign` class. Without implementation, compiler doesn't generate class and this results in linking error. There are no compile-time errors because *interface* of the class is declared though.

You should add such implementation, either in a separate `Campaign.m` file, or in one of already existing files.

Comment: Only CoreLocation, which I have added to the static library "Link binary with libraries". I get two undefined symbols errors that both refer to "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Campaign"

Comment: Is that "Campaign" class used by the app or the static library? Is that class actually **defined** somewhere?

Comment: It's an NSObject subclass both used by the app and the library. It is defined in Campaign.h. There is no Campaign.m since it's only an NSObject with some properties. I also added the Campaign.h header to the app.

Comment: Even if it's just NSObject subclass with properties you have to add `Campaign.m` (or, more precisely, `@implementation` section for `Campaign`). Otherwise compiler won't generate class and you'll get linker errors (which you already do).

Comment: That's it! I knew it would be something like that. Thanks very much!